# Typescript error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SchedulerProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, devexpress

Hey I am using  @devexpress/dx-react-scheduler, but i got stuck in an issue.

This is my Demo component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { ViewState } from '@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler';
import {
  Scheduler,
  DayView,
  Appointments,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui';

const currentDate = '2018-11-01';
const schedulerData = [
  { startDate: '2018-11-01T09:45', endDate: '2018-11-01T11:00', title: 'Meeting' },
  { startDate: '2018-11-01T12:00', endDate: '2018-11-01T13:30', title: 'Go to a gym' },
];

export default () => (
  <Paper>
    <Scheduler
      data={schedulerData}
    >
      <ViewState
        currentDate={currentDate}
      />
      <DayView
        startDayHour={9}
        endDayHour={14}
      />
      <Appointments />
    </Scheduler>
  </Paper>
);
```

This is my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "schedular",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "styled-components": "4.0.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "4.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.18.10",
    "@devexpress/dx-core": "3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler": "3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui": "3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-scheduler-core": "3.0.4",
    "@emotion/react": "11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.10.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.8.4",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.94",
    "@mui/material": "5.10.0",
    "@mui/system": "5.10.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "5.0.0-beta.4",
    "date-fns": "2.29.1",
    "dayjs": "1.11.4",
    "luxon": "3.0.1",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.47",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And The error is

**

> Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in src/Schedular.tsx:19:6

TS2322: Type '{ children: Element[]; data: { startDate: string; endDate: string; title: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SchedulerProps'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SchedulerProps'.
17 | export default () => (
18 |

> 19 |     <Scheduler
> |      ^^^^^^^^^
> 20 |       data={schedulerData}
> 21 |     >
> 22 |       <ViewState
> **

Thanks

Comment: Here Demo component name is changed by Schedular. so don't confuse  with this.